# User Interface on various devices in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am new in a Xamarin. I am working on my first Xamarin.Forms App. From the beginning I was testing everything using simulator iPhone 6s iOS 9.2 and everything was fine but at the end when I test it on iPhone 4s iOS 9.2 I got something strange UI as like attached in below image.
[image]

On every screen some of the part is going outside the screen. For above page Xaml code is given below. What I can do to make it working on every device in PCL only? I found same problem on Android too.
Xaml :

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="10" Spacing="10" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Button BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" Clicked="btnLogout_Click" Text="Logout" WidthRequest="80" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>

            <Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">                      
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <RowDefinition Height="110" />
                      <RowDefinition Height="110" /> 
                      <RowDefinition Height="110" />
                      <RowDefinition Height="110" />                                      
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<!--                    First Row-->
                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  BackgroundColor="#DAF7A6" >
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="comingInClicked"/>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label Text="Coming In" FontFamily="Arial Unicode MS"  TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.tileTextColor}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="#FFC300" >
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="attendanceClicked"/>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label Text="Leaves/&#10;Holidays" FontFamily="Arial Unicode MS" TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.tileTextColor}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#FF5733" >
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="statusClicked"/>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label Text="Status" FontFamily="Arial Unicode MS" TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.tileTextColor}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  BackgroundColor="#C70039" >
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="goingOutClicked"/>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label Text="Going Out" FontFamily="Arial Unicode MS" TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.tileTextColor}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"  BackgroundColor="#00EC93" >
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="eventCalendarClicked"/>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label Text="Event Calendar" FontFamily="Arial Unicode MS" TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.tileTextColor}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                    </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: So what you saw is simply by design as you use Grid with absolute layout.

Comment: Ok. I am not very much familiar with absolute layout. I am trying. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: In a absolute layout I am using Grid like -           **<ColumnDefinition  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,0.333,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />** and **<RowDefinition  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,0.333" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />** but I am not getting tiles in a square.

Comment: @LexLi I am able to use proportional width but in case of height its not working in the above code.

Comment: The problem is you are using explicit height and width values, and as a result it will only look right on the screen you are testing on. I would advise using relative layouts and render according to parent height and width for every visual element.